# Validate parameter value of module

Tags: system-verilog

Here is a simple module I am using to ask my question:

```
module counter  #(   
   parameter LIMIT = 15
   )(  input clk,               
       input rstn,
       output reg[7:0] out);   

  always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if (! rstn)
      out <= 0;
    else 
      if (out >= LIMIT)
        out <= 0;
      else
        out <= out + 1;
  end
    
endmodule
```

The compile/build/simulate process must *all* fail if the `LIMIT` is outside range 1 to 64. What is the correct way to do this? I am from VHDL background but writing this did not work:

```
   a_check_lfsr_size_others: assert (LIMIT >= 1 && LIMIT <= 64)
   else
      $fatal("LIMIT exceeded range of 1 to 64");
```

I got this error:

```
Reserved word "property" or "#0" missing after "assert".  Simple immediate assertions are illegal outside the procedural code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 20.11 *Elaboration system tasks*.

This gives an elaboration-time error if `LIMIT` is 65:

```
module counter  #(   
   parameter LIMIT = 15
   )(  input clk,               
       input rstn,
       output reg[7:0] out);   

  always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if (! rstn)
      out <= 0;
    else 
      if (out >= LIMIT)
        out <= 0;
      else
        out <= out + 1;
  end
    
  if ((LIMIT < 1) || (LIMIT > 64)) $fatal;

endmodule


module tb;
    counter i0 ();
    counter #(.LIMIT(33)) i1 ();
    counter #(.LIMIT(65)) i2 ();
endmodule
```

Example output (Synopsys VCS, version 2023.03):

```
Error-[FEST] $fatal elaboration system task
path: tb.i2
```

It also runs on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/QjAF) with VCS version 2021.09.